# Tensorflow serving returns [[[0]]]

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to use Tensorflow Serving to make predictions for my model.

This is the client that I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

"""A client that talks to tensorflow_model_server loaded with deepspeech model.
The client queries the service with the given audio and prints a ranked list
of decoded outputs to the standard output, one per line.
Typical usage example:
    deepspeech_client.py --server=localhost:9000 --file audio.wav
"""

import os
import sys

local_tf = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__)))), 'local_tf')
sys.path.append(local_tf)

import threading
from grpc.beta import implementations
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow_serving.apis import predict_pb2
from tensorflow_serving.apis import prediction_service_pb2

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '..'))
from util.text import ndarray_to_text
from util.audio import audiofile_to_input_vector

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('server', '', 'PredictionService host:port')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('file', '', 'Wave audio file')
# These need to match the constants used when training the deepspeech model
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('n_input', 26, 'Number of MFCC features')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('n_context', 9, 'Number of frames of context')
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

def _create_rpc_callback(event):
    def _callback(result_future):
        exception = result_future.exception()
        if exception:
            print exception
        else:
            results = tf.contrib.util.make_ndarray(result_future.result().outputs['outputs'])
            for result in results[0]:
                print ndarray_to_text(result)
        event.set()
    return _callback

def do_inference(hostport, audio):
    host, port = hostport.split(':')
    channel = implementations.insecure_channel(host, int(port))
    stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)

    request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
    request.model_spec.name = 'deepspeech'
    request.inputs['input'].CopyFrom(tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(audio))

    event = threading.Event()
    result_future = stub.Predict.future(request, 5.0)  # 5 seconds
    result_future.add_done_callback(_create_rpc_callback(event))
    if event.is_set() != True:
        event.wait()

def main(_):
    if not FLAGS.server:
        print 'please specify server host:port'
        return
    if not FLAGS.file:
        print 'pleace specify an audio file'
        return

    audio_waves = audiofile_to_input_vector(
                  FLAGS.file, FLAGS.n_input, FLAGS.n_context)
    audio = np.array([ audio_waves ])
    do_inference(FLAGS.server, audio)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

It's taken directly from an older commit of the [Mozilla DeepSpeech](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/blob/2740336d089b592f905e0236a686aa71096dd28f/serving_client/deepspeech_client.py) implementation.

I have a trained model (from the same commit) that I'm trying to use to make predictions. I'm using the `LDC193S1.wav` file to try and make predictions.

When I run the model, I get back a response that is equal to

```
dtype: DT_INT64 tensor_shape { dim { size: 1 } dim { size: 1 } dim { size: 1 } } int64_val: 0 [[[0]]]
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You show the result and ask how it can be fixed but it would help if you specified what you expected or want the output to be.  For example, is the shape of the output not what you want, or the value is too low...

Comment: I would expect the result to be non-null. During training, the model predicts that value correctly as "She had your dark suit in greasy wash water all year", so it seems reasonable to expect that the exported model would have the same result.